# LeetCode C++ Convert char[] to string, throws AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow error

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

I'm learning C++, and on LeetCode, converting a `char[]` to a `string` gives a `AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow` error.

```
string test1() /* Line 70 */
{
    char test[] = "11";
    return string(test);
}

string test2() /* Line 76 */
{
    char test[] = {'1', '1'};
    return string(test);
}

int main()
{
    cout << test1() << endl;
    cout << test2() << endl;
}
```

In this code above, `test1` returns "11" and `test2` gives the error below with ASAN on. Why does this happen? Aren't they just different ways to initialize a char array?

```
==87465==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffee2400c22 at pc 0x00010d837634 bp 0x7ffee2400ad0 sp 0x7ffee2400290
READ of size 3 at 0x7ffee2400c22 thread T0
pc_0x10d837633###func_wrap_strlen###file_<null>###line_3###obj_(libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x1a633)
pc_0x10d803a14###func_std::__1::char_traits<char>::length(char const*)###file___string###line_253###obj_(CCC:x86_64+0x100005a14)
pc_0x10d803950###func_std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::nullptr_t>(char const*)###file_string###line_819###obj_(CCC:x86_64+0x100005950)
pc_0x10d80326c###func_std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::nullptr_t>(char const*)###file_string###line_817###obj_(CCC:x86_64+0x10000526c)
pc_0x10d80338f###func_test2()###file_p67-add-binary.cpp###line_79###obj_(CCC:x86_64+0x10000538f)
pc_0x10d803569###func_main###file_p67-add-binary.cpp###line_85###obj_(CCC:x86_64+0x100005569)
pc_0x7fff6cf80cc8###func_start###file_<null>###line_2###obj_(libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1acc8)
Address 0x7ffee2400c22 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 34 in frame
pc_0x10d80328f###func_test2()###file_p67-add-binary.cpp###line_77###obj_(CCC:x86_64+0x10000528f)
  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 34) 'test' (line 78) <== Memory access at offset 34 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x1a633) in wrap_strlen+0x183
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1fffdc480130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc480140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc480150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc480160: f1 f1 f1 f1 f8 f2 f8 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc480170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x1fffdc480180: f1 f1 f1 f1[02]f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc480190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1
  0x1fffdc4801a0: f8 f8 f8 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3
  0x1fffdc4801b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc4801c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdc4801d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
```

Comment: String literals are null terminated. `"11"` is `{'1', '1', '\0'}`.

Comment: And without that terminator, the `string` constructor doesn't know when to stop reading the input you gave it. It will keep looking for the terminator past the end of the array and into the unknown reaches outside the array. This results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because the C++ standard cannot predict (and mandating the result would almost certainly slow the program down because it would have to perform extra checking) what will happen should a program access out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `char *` to be processed properly as a string, you must make sure it's null-terminated:

```
char test[] {'1', '1', '\0'};
```

String literals do that automatically. `"11"` is the same as `{'1', '1', '\0'}`.

---

Alternatively, you can pass the number of characters to read:

```
string str(test, sizeof test);
```