# std::string constructed from subrange of char array calls strlen

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strlen, address-sanitizer

It is similar to [LeetCode C++ Convert char[] to string, throws AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339674/leetcode-c-convert-char-to-string-throws-addresssanitizer-stack-buffer-ove)

The code is

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    char buf[10] = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6};
    std::string s{buf, 2, 3};
    return 0;
}
```

Execution ends up with address sanitizer complaining about `strlen`'s `stack-buffer-overflow`:

```
$ clang++ -g -fsanitize=address foo.cpp ; ./a.out
=================================================================
==1001715==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd76b2510a at pc 0x00000042f029 bp 0x7ffd76b250b0 sp 0x7ffd76b24870
READ of size 23 at 0x7ffd76b2510a thread T0
    #0 0x42f028 in strlen (/tmp/a.out+0x42f028)
    #1 0x7fd6de786e9b in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x145e9b)
    #2 0x4c6cfe in main /tmp/foo.cpp:6:19
    #3 0x7fd6de2d60b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16
    #4 0x41c3fd in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x41c3fd)
```

I'd expect that `std::string s{buf, 2, 3};` calls a constructor overload with known bounds (start at 2, length is 3). Why is it calling `strlen()`? Which overload is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check cpp insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/fe8ef2a2). It is great tool to see what was used during overload resolution.

It generates this:

```cpp
#include <string>

int main()
{
  char buf[10] = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6};
  std::string s = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >{std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(buf, std::allocator<char>()), 2, 3};
  return 0;
}
```

After cleaning up to make this more readable:

```cpp
#include <string>

int main()
{
  char buf[10] = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6};
  std::string s = std::string{std::string(buf), 2, 3};
  return 0;
}
```

So note that `buf` is first converted to `std::string` and this conversion requires `strlen`. Since your array do not contain terminating zero buffer overflow happens.

Comment: [`[string.cons]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#6) says a temporary `string_view` is used, not `string`. I guess it's not possible to observe the difference, but a `string` is misleading, since no actual heap allocation happens.

Comment: Yes since C++17 [constructor nr 11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) should be used (is should win overload resolution). But tools says it is not used even when C++2a is selected. Also call stack from address sanitizer points to `std::string{buf, allocator()}` https://godbolt.org/z/j63EaW33G
So maybe bug to compiler should be reported.

Comment: Could the stack be wrong? I'm looking at libstdc++ implementation ([here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L638-L642) and [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L125-L126)), and it looks like it does the right thing (uses `string_view`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat take a look on this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9hMdTfs6M) (invalid argument is passed on purpose to see what compiler tries to resolve overloads). Note that it says: `template argument deduction/substitution failed` for problematic constructor. I'm still trying figure out why. At least this explain fallback to conversion to string.

Comment: Ok I've found problem here: ['__not_<is_convertible<const _Tp&, const _CharT*>>>::value,'](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L116-L121). Last part of condition is not meet since array decays to pointer to characters.

Comment: Oh my! Thought it was a libstdc++ bug first, but libc++ does the same thing! Should we ask a new question about this?

Comment: Here is a question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70591571/1387438

Answer (score 3):

HolyBlackCat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582232/2079303) and Marek R's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582463/2079303) explain why it's wrong. Here is a solution using the (pointer, count) constructor:

```
std::string s{buf + 2, 3};
```