# Why is SFINAE for one of the std::basic_string constructors so restrictive?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, std, c++20

### Background

Discussion about this was started under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582463/1387438) for quite simple question.

### Problem

This simple code has unexpected overload resolution of constructor for `std::basic_string`:

```cpp
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s{"some string to test", 2, 3};
    return 0;
}
```

Now someone was expecting that this will  invoke this constructor:

[std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::basic_string - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

> |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | template< class T > basic_string( const T& t, size_type pos, size_type n, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); | (since C++17) | (11) |
> | template< class T > constexpr basic_string( const T& t, size_type pos, size_type const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); | (since C++20) | (11) |

Rationale is based on section of this c++ standard:

[[string.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#6)

> `template<class T> constexpr basic_string(const T& t, size_type pos, size_type n, const Allocator& a = Allocator());`
>
> [5](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#5) *Constraints*: is_­convertible_­v<const T&, basic_­string_­view<charT, traits>> is true[.](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#5.sentence-1)
>
> [6](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#6) *Effects*: Creates a variable, sv, as if by basic_­string_­view<charT, traits> sv = t; and then behaves the same as: basic_string(sv.substr(pos, n), a);

Now when this code is processed by [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHN0cmluZz4KCmludCBtYWluKCkgewogICAgc3RkOjpzdHJpbmcgc3sic29tZSBzdHJpbmcgdG8gdGVzdCIsIDIsIDN9OwogICAgcmV0dXJuIDA7Cn0K&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) result is different then expected:

```cpp
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s = std::basic_string<char>{std::basic_string<char>("some string to test", std::allocator<char>()), 2, 3};
  return 0;
}
```

After collapsing this code to respective type definitions of `std::string` it becomes this:

```cpp
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s = std::string{std::string("some string to test"), 2, 3};
  return 0;
}
```

So conversion of string literal to `std::string` was performed and then constructor in form [(3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) was used. So undesired extra allocation is performed.

I'm sure this is not fault of tool I did other experiments to confirm that. Here is a [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/839ah54jf). Assembly clearly follows this pattern.

### Analysis

To find explanation of this problem I've [introduced an error](https://godbolt.org/z/8Y31c3K19) to this code, so error report prints possible overload resolutions. Here is most interesting part of error report:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/basic_string.h:771:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _Tp&, size_type, size_type, const _Alloc&) [with <template-parameter-2-2> = _Tp; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
  771 |         basic_string(const _Tp& __t, size_type __pos, size_type __n,
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/basic_string.h:771:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/char_traits.h:42,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/string:40,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = void]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/basic_string.h:156:8:   required by substitution of 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> template<class _Tp, class _Res> using _If_sv = std::enable_if_t<std::__and_<std::is_convertible<const _Tp&, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >, std::__not_<std::is_convertible<const _Tp*, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>*> >, std::__not_<std::is_convertible<const _Tp&, const _CharT*> > >::value, _Res> [with _Tp = char [20]; _Res = void; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/basic_string.h:769:30:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220104/include/c++/12.0.0/type_traits:2614:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
 2614 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

So overload [(11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has been rejected by SFINAE.

Related standard library code looks like this:
[Overload (11)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L638-L642) of std::basic_string constructor:

```cpp
    template<typename _Tp, typename = _If_sv<_Tp, void>>
    basic_string(const _Tp& __t, size_type __pos, size_type __n,
             const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
    : basic_string(_S_to_string_view(__t).substr(__pos, __n), __a) { }
```

And here is implementation of [_If_sv](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L116-L121):

```cpp
    template<typename _Tp, typename _Res>
    using _If_sv = enable_if_t<
      __and_<is_convertible<const _Tp&, __sv_type>,
         __not_<is_convertible<const _Tp*, const basic_string*>>,
         __not_<is_convertible<const _Tp&, const _CharT*>>>::value,
      _Res>;
```

So last part of this condition: `__not_<is_convertible<const _Tp&, const _CharT*>>>::value` is a problem since clearly char array (string literal) is convertible to pointer to characters.

### Question

Why does the implementation of `_If_sv` look like this? What is the rationale of having this extra condition which is not mentioned in the standard?

If I understand overload resolution correctly, this extra condition is obsolete, since when first argument is `std::string` overloads [(3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has priority over overload [(11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) as exact match of non template function. On the other hand if an argument is something other than `std::string` and it is convertible to `std::string_view` then template overload [(11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) should win and extra allocation is avoided.

Is this a bug in the implementation of the standard library or did I miss something?

Why are these extra SFINAE conditions needed?

### Bonus question

Is there a nice way to write a test which detects this issue?
Some ways to verify that a proper overload has been selected without modifying tested code (in this case `std::basic_string`)?

Comment: Interestingly, both libstdc++ and libc++ do this...

Comment: Must you use a *braced-init-list*?

Comment: @jxh Braces or parenthesis will not change anything here.

Comment: The SFINAE rules were introduced in [library issue2946](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2946)

Comment: This is a libstdc++ bug. Reported [#103919](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103919), already fixed on trunk.

Comment: I see that trunk version of `gcc` (future 11.3) on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G9WcEvdhn) now optimizes this to the limit, currently there is no allocation for a string :) at all (small string optimization did job too).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++14 your code always created a new `std::string` temporary, there was no constructor taking `const char*` or `std::string_view` that could be used.

In C++17 your code *should* create a `string_view` and avoid the temporary. GCC's implementation is overconstrained and so still behaves like C++14, creating the extra temporary.

> Why implementation of `_If_sv` looks like this? What is rationale to have this extra conditions not mentioned in standard?

It has three conditions, and two of them *are* in the standard. And the third has a reason too.

The `_If_sv` helper implements the constraints needed by every `basic_string` function that takes a `basic_string_view` *except* the one constructor you're asking about. That one has a slightly weaker constraint, allowing `const CharT*` pointers to be passed to it and converted to a string view. Because libstdc++ uses the same `_If_sv` helper for that constructor, it doesn't work as the standard requires. I've fixed that now ([PR 103919](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR103919)).

Of the three conditions in `_If_sv`:

- The "convertible to `string_view` one is required by the standard.
- The "not convertible to `const CharT*`" one is required by the standard for all functions *except* the constructor you're asking about.
- The final condition, the "not convertible to `basic_string`" one, was added to fix a [regression I discovered](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/libstdc++/2017-09/msg00066.html), caused by the constraints specified by the standard. That problem is described below, for people who don't like clicking on links to leave SO.

> If I understood overload resolution correctly this extra conditions are obsolete,

Nope.

> since when first argument is `std::string` overloads (3) has priority over overload (11) as exact match of non template function.

Yes, if it's a `std::string` then the other constructor would be chosen anyway. The "not convertible to `std::string`" constraint is redundant here, because another constructor would be chosen anyway. It's harmless, but redundant. But what if the argument is not `std::string`, but is something *derived* from `std::string`? Consider:

```cpp
class tstring : public std::string
{
public:
  tstring() : std::string() {}
  tstring(tstring&& s) : std::string(std::move(s)) {}
};
```

In C++14 this uses the `basic_string(basic_string&&)` move constructor, as intended. In C++17 it uses `basic_string(const T&, const Alloc& = Alloc())` because the `tstring&&` argument is convertible to `string_view`. That means we make a copy of `s` instead of moving it as intended.

The additional constraint that `T` is not convertible to `std::string` removes the new `string_view` overload from consideration here, so the move constructor is used again. So that extra constraint is harmless for cases where the constructor wouldn't be chosen anyway, but **useful** for cases where the new `basic_string(const T&, const Alloc&)` constructor would be chosen but shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that last part:

```
__not_<is_convertible<const _Tp&, const _CharT*>>>::value
```

is added to `_If_sv` for preventing ambiguity between these 2 constructors:

```
constexpr basic_string( const CharT* s,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); //(5)

template< class T >
explicit basic_string( const T& t,
                       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); //(10)
```

(10) should be selected if `T` is convertible to `string_view`. But (10) is `explicit` so this problem should be selected without `{}`. I don't think this check is needed in `_If_sv`. They probably have used same `_If_sv` for both overloads (10) and (11) that you mentioned, so both are working incorrectly now.

Comment: as I point out in overload resolution none template functions with exact type match have priority over template versions. If you have some experiment or document proving that I'm wrong in this point then it would be nice to see it.

Comment: @MarekR from this answer, I meant that you are probably right. That additional check in `_Is_sv` is wrong and it is probably a bug.

Comment: To be clear, the standard mandates the 'additional' check for (10) so it's necessary and correct there.